# Acesso a funções do banco de dados utilizando Laravel

Tags: laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.8

Olá, sou novo ao utilizar o Laravel e tenho uma dúvida. Para acessar funções pré definidas em um banco de dados, faço diretamente do controller ou teria uma maneira mais adequada para tal processo?

Grato.

Comment: Exemplifique o que você relatou ... função ??? qual funções ???

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, tenho uma função no postgresql que quando executo a query com algumas variáveis, ele faz a busca dentro das tabelas do banco e me retorna um array com as informações pertinentes. Acabei resolvendo utilizando o collect. É que eu queria saber se existe outras formas de coletar os dados.

Comment: Se você colocar na sua pergunta o que você fez fica fácil ter alguma solução, mas, só texto sem exemplo minimo não tem como !!! Se exemplificar ...